# how to make window split in half in windows 10

Tags: windows

In Win 7 whenever I need to make a window to occupy half left or half right of the desktop, all I need to do is to click <kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd><=</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd>=></kbd>.

I noticed in Win 10, when i do the same thing, it won't snap full half.  Rather it will snap top left (1/4 of the screen instead of 1/2 of the screen).

Can someone showed me how to revert the set up back to Win 7?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 supports snapping to corners as well as sides of the screen. While My computer first snaps to the side, and then allows me to snap up or down, perhaps your computer does it differently.

**Try first pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>⇦</kbd>, and then pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>⇩</kbd>.** This should first make it snap to the left corner, and then expand it down. If your computer snaps to the bottom corner by default, try pressing <kbd>⇧</kbd> instead of <kbd>⇩</kbd>

Have a play around with the <kbd>Win</kbd> and Arrow keys, there's quite a bit of possibilities in Windows 10. You can even wrap around to the other side of the screen!

Comment: thanks.  What i want is to disable snapping to the corners and instead snap directly to the side of the screen.  Ay idea how??

Comment: Ah alright. Just for clarity: When you try snapping, you start out with the window maximized and no other windows already snapped to a corner?

Comment: Yes.  Or when I open a window (it is not maximized) and i like to simply snap to left half and right half just by pressing windows + left or windows + right keys.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I have no idea what might be causing this. Sorry!